Правильный подсчет доли простоя каналов обслуживания СМО
Как правильно подсчитать долю простоя каналов обслуживания?
При увеличении времени работы мы получаем довольно высокую погрешность:
Доля простоя A ожидаемая = 0,23
Доля простоя B ожидаемая = 0,38

Схема СМО:

import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
# Параметры системы
simulation_time = 30 * 60  # время симуляции в секундах (30 минут)
lambda_ = 3  # среднее количество требований в минуту
arrival_probability = lambda_ / 60  # вероятность прибытия требования за каждую секунду
mu_A = 1  # средняя скорость обслуживания на канале A (требований за минуту)
mu_B = 3  # средняя скорость обслуживания на канале B (требований за минуту)
max_queue_length = 2  # максимальная длина очереди
 
# Вероятность обслуживания за каждую секунду
service_probability_A = mu_A / 60
service_probability_B = mu_B / 60
 
# Состояние системы
queue = 0  # текущее количество требований в очереди
failures = 0  # количество отказов
 
# Состояние каналов
busy_A = False  # канал A занят или нет
busy_B = False  # канал B занят или нет
 
# Счетчики времени простоя
idle_time_A = 0
idle_time_B = 0
 
sum_received_claims = 0  # сумма пришедших требований
 
# Отслеживание данных по времени
queue_over_time = []
failures_per_minute = []
 
# Имитация в течение заданного времени
for t in range(simulation_time):
    print("---Секунда:\t", t+1, "---")
    # Прибытие требований
    if random.random() < arrival_probability:
        print("Пришел клиент")
        if queue < max_queue_length:
            queue += 1
            print("Текущая очередь: ", queue)
            sum_received_claims += 1
        else:
            print("человек отклонен")
            failures += 1
 
    # Проверка возможности начать обслуживание на каналах
    if not busy_A and queue > 0:
        print("Начато обслуживание в А")
        queue -= 1
        print("Текущая очередь: ", queue)
        busy_A = True
    elif not busy_B and queue > 0:
        print("Начато обслуживание в B")
        queue -= 1
        print("Текущая очередь: ", queue)
        busy_B = True
 
    # Время простоя каналов
    if not busy_A and queue == 0:
        idle_time_A += 1
    if not busy_B and queue == 0:
        idle_time_B += 1
 
    # Проверка освобождения каналов
    if busy_A and random.random() < service_probability_A:
        print("Завершено обслуживание в А")
        busy_A = False
        if queue > 0:
            print("Начало обслуживания в A")
            busy_A = True
            queue -= 1
    if busy_B and random.random() < service_probability_B:
        print("Завершено обслуживание в B")
        busy_B = False
        if queue > 0:
            print("Начало обслуживания в B")
            busy_B = True
            queue -= 1
 
    # Сбор данных каждую минуту
    if t == 0:
        queue_over_time.append(queue)
        failures_per_minute.append(failures)
    elif (t+1) % 60 == 0:
        queue_over_time.append(queue)
        failures_per_minute.append(failures)
 
# Среднее время простоя канала A и B
average_idle_A = idle_time_A / simulation_time
average_idle_B = idle_time_B / simulation_time
 
print("Общее количество пришедших требований: ", sum_received_claims)
print("Количество обслуженных требований", sum_received_claims-failures)
print("Доля обслуженных требований:", (sum_received_claims - failures) / sum_received_claims)
print("Количество отказов:", failures)
print("Доля отказов:", failures / sum_received_claims)
print("Средняя доля времени простоя канала A:", average_idle_A)
print("Средняя доля времени простоя канала B:", average_idle_B)
print("Средняя доля времени простоя обоих каналов обслуживания:", (average_idle_A + average_idle_B) / 2)
 
# Графики
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 9))
# Добавляем точки на график очереди во времени
plt.plot(list(range(0, simulation_time+1, 60)), queue_over_time, marker='o', linestyle='-', markersize=6)
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel("Время (в минутах)")
plt.ylabel("Количество требований в очереди")
plt.title("Состояние очереди по минутам")
plt.show()
 
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 9))
# Добавляем точки на график отказов за каждую минуту
plt.plot(list(range(0, simulation_time+1, 60)), failures_per_minute, marker='o', linestyle='-', markersize=6, color='red')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel("Время (в минутах)")
plt.ylabel("Количество отказов")
plt.title("Отказы за каждую минуту")
plt.show()

